Drizzle query builder function type issue using findMany()
I'm trying to write a query builder function in Drizzle using findMany() function that handles pagination and parameter request.
The issue is, i'm unable to use orderBy in "with".
The function I made is:
export const paginate = async <
  TSchema extends TablesRelationalConfig,
  TFields extends TableRelationalConfig,
>(
  qb: RelationalQueryBuilder<TSchema, TFields>,
  model: PgTable,
  requestQuery: ListSchema,
  allowedFilters: Record<string, string | ((column: any, value: any) => SQL)>,
) => {
  const columns = getTableColumns(model);
  const {
    page = 1,
    perPage = 25,
    orderBy,
    sort = "asc",
    ...filters
  } = requestQuery;

  const validSort = sort.toLowerCase() === "asc" ? asc : desc;

  const validOrderBy =
    orderBy && orderBy in columns ? (orderBy as keyof typeof columns) : "id";

  const whereClause = buildWhereClause(filters, model, allowedFilters);
  const data = await qb.findMany({
    limit: perPage,
    offset: (page - 1) * perPage,
    orderBy: validSort(columns[validOrderBy]),
    where: whereClause,
    with: {
      models: {
        with: {
          prints: true,
        },
      },
      status: {
        limit: 1,
        orderBy: (status, { desc }) => [desc(status.createdAt)],
      },
    },
  });

  const c = await db.select({ count: count() }).from(model).where(whereClause);

  return {
    data,
    count: c[0].count,
  };
};


and im using it in this way:
const { data, count } = await paginate(
db.query.orders,
orders,
query,
allowedFilters,

);
But im getting error at status.createdAt:
TS2339: Property createdAt does not exist on type
{ [K in keyof ([FindTableByDBName<TSchema, TFields["relations"]["status"]["referencedTableName"]>["columns"]] extends [never] ? {} : FindTableByDBName<TSchema, TFields["relations"]["status"]["referencedTableName"]>["columns"])]: ([...] extends [...] ? {} : FindTableByDBName<...>["columns"])[K]; }
however: using adding type "any" would fix the error and function works properly. I just want to have the correct types.
P.S, overall goal is to have the with outside and pass to this function to make it more dynamic, but i still stuck here.
would be grateful if you help me on this.
Thanks.
